# I am looking for LBSP-Search-Common.xsd

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the Here Maps rest api for geocoding and would like to get the full xsd definition of:
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/xsd/LBSP-Search-Search.xsd
but my tools (nor I) can't find these imported .xsds:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Common/4" schemaLocation="LBSP-Common.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Common/4" schemaLocation="LBSP-Search-Common.xsd"/>
```

I've googled the file names and found http://route.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/xsd/LBSP-Common.xsd but it is:
- a different version # 
and I can't find the other one.

Any help in finding these files would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for xsd files to help parse Geocoder XML responses, please see the following URLs.
All xsd locations relevant to Geocoder are listed on the following web page: http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/xsd/index.html

Comment: Thanks Philip the index of files link was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for these 
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/xsd/LBSP-Common.xsd
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/xsd/LBSP-Search-Common.xsd